# dropdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have a problem when I run a script to restore **postgres database**.

[image: Error Image]

The script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

    CURRENT_DIR=$(cd $(dirname "$0");pwd)
    MYPATH=$CURRENT_DIR/../..

    function delFile(){
            if [ -e "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" ];then
                rm /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
            fi
            if [ -e "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock" ];then
                rm /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock
            fi
    }

    function restore(){

            $MYPATH/pgsql/bin/dropdb -U xsadmin xs_mng
            $MYPATHHOME/pgsql/bin/createdb xs_mng -U xsadmin
            $MYPATH_HOME/pgsql/bin/psql -d xs_mng -U xsadmin < $MYPATH/pgsql/bin/backup.sql

    }

    restore
```

Comment: And the problem is: the  new postgres ,if you attempt to start it, refuses to start?

Comment: no,the postgres has not changed

Comment: Note: `$MYPATHHOME` and `$MYPATH_HOME`  are  undefined

Comment: Thanks,but the issue is existing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check whether PostgreSQL service is started and listening to Unix socket.

Try issuing `netstat -an` in order to check this.

Second, the user 'xsadmin' you're trying to execute PG admin commands must exist and have permission to connect to the default database (template1?) and have permission to create new databases.